# MigLayout JTextArea is not shrinking when used with linewrap=true

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, miglayout

If I use a `JTextArea` with `MigLayout` like this:

```
MigLayout thisLayout = new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[]20[]");
   this.setLayout(thisLayout);
   {
jLabel1 = new JLabel();
this.add(jLabel1, "cell 0 0");
jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
  }
  {
 jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
this.add(jTextArea1, "cell 0 1 2 1,growx");
jTextArea1.setText("jTextArea1");
jTextArea1.setLineWrap(false);
   }
```

then the `JTextArea` grows and shrinks perfectly when resizing the window. When I set the linewrap to true the `JTextArea` is not shrinking when I make the window smaller again.

Comment: A simple and fast solution you can find here !

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7833439/2530822

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `JTextArea`'s automatically have their minimum width set anytime they resize.  Details are available on the [MigLayout forum](http://migcalendar.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1972).  To roughly summarize, create a panel that contains the `JTextArea` and gives you further control over the resize behavior.  Here's an excerpt from the above forum post:

```
static class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable
{
  MyPanel(LayoutManager layout)
  {
     super(layout);
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
  {
     return getPreferredSize();
  }

  public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
  {
     return 0;
  }

  public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
  {
     return false;
  }

  public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
  {
     return true;
  }

  public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
  {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Then, wherever you would use the JTextArea, use the panel containing the text area:

```
MigLayout thisLayout = new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[]20[]");
this.setLayout(thisLayout);
{
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    this.add(jLabel1, "cell 0 0");
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
}
{
    JPanel textAreaPanel = new MyPanel(new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow,fill]", "[]"));
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
    textAreaPanel.add(jTextArea1);
    this.add(textAreaPanel, "cell 0 1 2 1,grow,wmin 10");
    jTextArea1.setText("jTextArea1");
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kaleb. I also tried to put it in a scrollpane, which also works fine. Regards Marcel

Answer (score 23):

I just discovered that this can simply be resolved by changing the line

```
this.add(jTextArea1, "cell 0 1 2 1,growx");
```

to

```
this.add(jTextArea1, "cell 0 1 2 1,growx, wmin 10");
```

and no extra panels are needed. Setting an explicit minimum size is what does the trick.

Explanation: see the note under the section on padding in the MiGLayout whitepaper:

http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/whitepaper.html

Comment: +1 This seems to solve problems with other stubborn components, too. In my case my chromium browser frame wouldn't shrink until adding a minimum size.

Comment: Confirmed, this works, and much easier to use than the accepted answer. You can specify `"wmin 0"` which in my opinion makes it clear that is added to work around an issue. +1 for your minimal fix.

Comment: Works perfectly. In my case, I had to make sure the component had both a minimum size _and_ a preferred size.